# how to build dom object into html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

i tried to use this

```
$("#aa").insertAfter($("<input type='text' name='category' value='h2' /\>"));
```

it seems didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) here, like this:

```
$("#aa").after("<input type='text' name='category' value='h2' /\>");
```

[`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) is the opposite, it takes the first element and tries to place it after the second element (or selector, whichever you give it), so it would look like this:

```
$("<input type='text' name='category' value='h2' /\>").insertAfter("#aa");
```